# when click on button or icon i want to open uber mobile application in my mobile using angular js in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, uber-api

I Want to use Uber Ride Requests via click on icon or button in my mobile application which is in ionic-angularJS so if user want he can book his Ride using from my mobile application.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with a cordova plugin, called StartApp (https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp).

You will need to know the schema for both Android and iOS of the app that you want to open.

This link might be useful:
http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-launch-external-application-with-ionic-framework/